# move data from one table to other table with different table structure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

I am creating a generic data upload app where user creates the table structure and upload the data.

I have generic data table. with following structure.

```
--------------------------------------
tableId | ColumName | rowNo | CellData
```

now user will creates template and upload data in csv format for that template.

suppose user created following template.

```
----------------------------------------
colum1 | colum2  | colum3 | colum4
```

and insert data as follows

```
TemplateOne

colum1 | colum2  | colum3 | colum4
-----------------------------------
x1     |  x2     |  x3    |  x4   
A1     |  A2     |  A3    |  A4   
B1     |  B2     |  B3    |  B4
```

I want to move this data to generic data table as follows.

```
   tableId  | ColumName | rowNo | CellData 
--------------------------------------
TemplateOne | colum1    |   1   | X1
TemplateOne | colum1    |   2   | A1
TemplateOne | colum1    |   3   | B1
TemplateOne | colum2    |   1   | X2
TemplateOne | colum2    |   2   | A2
TemplateOne | colum2    |   3   | B2
TemplateOne | colum3    |   1   | X3
TemplateOne | colum3    |   2   | A3
TemplateOne | colum3    |   3   | B3  
TemplateOne | colum4    |   1   | X4
TemplateOne | colum4    |   2   | A4
TemplateOne | colum4    |   3   | B4
```

I am trying to develop a dynamic sql for the same. Just want to know if there is any easier way of doing this.

If Yes please suggest.

Comment: Do you have `rowNo` on `TemplateOne`? If so it is much easier.

Comment: yes I have identity column. If not I can use a table variable for that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `unpivot`

```
select 'TemplateOne' as tableid, ColumnName, celldata
from TemplateOne
unpivot (celldata for ColumnName in (colum1, colum2, colum3, colum4)
        ) as unpvt;
```

To do this in general, you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I will try unpivot but I am unable to relate my example with your code (might be lack of unpivot knowledge).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement to copy data from `table1` to `table2`.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1,col2 ...)
SELECT col1,col2... FROM table1;
```

The Document is here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

---

Your SQL could go something like this:

```
INSERT INTO generic (tableId, ColumName,rowNo,CellData)
SELECT 'TemplateOne' AS tableId, 'colum1' AS ColumName, rowNo, colum1 AS CellData
FROM TemplateOne
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TemplateOne' AS tableId, 'colum2' AS ColumName, rowNo, colum2 AS CellData
FROM TemplateOne
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TemplateOne' AS tableId, 'colum3' AS ColumName, rowNo, colum3 AS CellData
FROM TemplateOne
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TemplateOne' AS tableId, 'colum4' AS ColumName, rowNo, colum4 AS CellData
FROM TemplateOne;
```

DEMO : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3e84a/1

Hope this helps.